# Why does json.parse break? and how to fix it

Tags: javascript, python

I have the following data coming in from my server into my js code, from my server.

```
{"triggers": [{"message_type": "sms","recipients": "[\"+91xxxxxxxxx\",\"+91xxxxxxxxx\"]","message": "This is a test"}]}
```

My code parses the above json string in the following manner.

```
data = '{"triggers": [{"message_type": "sms","recipients": "[\"+91xxxxxxxx\",\"+91xxxxxxxx\"]","message": "This is a test"}]}'
parsed = JSON.parse(data);
```

This throws the following exception

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token + in JSON at position 54
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (entry.html:2), <anonymous>:1:6)
    at entry.html:298
```

I did a little bit of further digging and found the source of the json string.
Here is where the string is coming in from my python code

```
data = {"recipients": "[\"+91xxxxxxxxx\",\"+91xxxxxxxx\"]"} # This data comes in from my database, and I can't do anything about what quotes are used.
javascript_supplied_data = json.dumps(data) #This data goes to the frontend via webhook
```

I tried putting the same data into a json view via [this](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) online viewer, and it didn't throw any error and displayed the data correctly.

What I can't understand is, I am doing a json.dumps in my python code, so the string response should be json parsable. So why does JSON.parse throw this error?

Is there something wrong with the json libraries at the python end or the javascript end, or am I too much of a noob?.

Please help me figure out what is causing this issue, and how to solve it.

**NOTE**: I don't have any control over the string that comes in from the server.

Comment: Note that in javascript string literals "\" has special meaning but it does not have special meaning in pure data (if you read from a file or get value of an input or make an ajax request etc.). So the string you receive from the server and the string you type in your source code cannot be the same to be identical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you have valid JSON, but put it in a string literal, the escapes treated by the literal notation in JavaScript make the string different. The backslashes are interpreted as for escaping the next character.

So either you have to go through the string literal and double all the backslashes, or you can apply `String.raw` to the string literal as template string:

```js
var data = String.raw`{"triggers": [{"message_type": "sms","recipients": "[\"+91xxxxxxxx\",\"+91xxxxxxxx\"]","message": "This is a test"}]}`;
var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
console.log(parsed);
```

Note however, that the JSON you posted at the start of your question is valid.

On the other hand, the error you get indicates that the `\"` just before the first `+` is interpreted as just `"`. This means the `\` is not actually there when the string is received from the server. This is usually caused by a similar escaping problem at the server side, where the programmer *intended* to send the backslash to the client, but actually just escaped the `"` on the server, which resulted in only the `"` being sent to the client and not `\"`.

Comment: Hi, I think I updated my question, while you were posting your answer. Could you go through the question again? I am not really sure if your current answer can help me.

Comment: I added an extra paragraph. It would be helpful if you would tell us how you see that there is a backslash before the double quote in the JSON. Did you `console.log` it on the client, or are you looking at the server code?

Comment: Data is passed by the python code as a "jinja variable" into the html code using flask. (This is what my backend guy told me). I saw the json string by viewing the source using google chromes inspector.

Comment: If you see it in the HTML source like that, then the server is not the problem (well, it depends *where* in the HTML content. In an attribute? In a tag content?). Can you produce a fiddle with that JSON in the HTML source, just like you have it, and add the JS code with which you interpret that HTML content as JSON?

Comment: It is inside a script tag. Those two lines are exactly as I have put them. Except for changes to hide the phone numbers and some extra data.
I tested the thing with the data I posted as well, and same issue.

Comment: I figured out how to use this. Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use single quotes here while escape sequence.

if we use double quotes for escape sequence here it will result in

```
"recipients": "["+91xxxxxxxx","+91xxxxxxxx"]"
```

double quotes inside double quotes which is why your code breaks.

```js
data = '{"triggers": [{"message_type": "sms","recipients": "[\'+91xxxxxxxx\',\'+91xxxxxxxx\']","message": "This is a test"}]}';

parsed = JSON.parse(data);

console.log(parsed)
```

Comment: Apologies for adding extra details after you posted your answer.